Multiple echos are not shown on multiple lines when executed through autocommand
If I open Vim with
$ vim -u NONE

and then enter
:set cmdheight=2
:exe 'echo "Hello" | echo "World"'

I see both Hello and World, on seperate lines, each occupying one of the 2 lines I made space for with the first command.
If I now run
:autocmd TextChangedI * exe 'echo "Hello" | echo "World"'

and then I start typing, I only see World occupying the first of those lines.
Why is that?

A redraw is clearing those messages. Use :echomsg and check with the :messages comamnd

Yeah, @ChristianBrabandt, I saw those (I should have written echom instead of echo in the question, after my last attempt), but the point is that I want the two messages to be visible as I type (clearly they are dynamic, in the real case, not literal strings).

I'm looking at :h :redraw and :h 'lz', but I haven't found the solution yet.
